# Adding a Node to a BST recursively using comparable in Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, comparable

So I've been trying to insert or add a node to a BST recursively and I'm stumped. I keep getting 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 which I'm assuming is being caused by the recursion, but I don't exactly know where to go from here and would love some direction if anyone could help provide it. :)

```
public void add(Type obj) {

    TreeNode<Type> newNode = new TreeNode<Type>(obj);

    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        addNode(root, newNode);
    }
}


private void addNode(TreeNode<Type> current, TreeNode<Type> newNode) {

    current = root;
    if (current == null) {
        current = newNode;
    } else if (newNode.getValue().compareTo(current.getValue()) < 0) {

        if (current.getLeft() == null) {
            current.setLeft(newNode);

        } else {
            addNode(current.getLeft(), newNode);
        }
    } else if (newNode.getValue().compareTo(current.getValue()) > 0) {

        if (current.getRight() == null) {
            current.setRight(newNode);
        } else {
            addNode(current.getRight(), newNode);
        }
    }
}//end add
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void addNode(TreeNode<Type> current, TreeNode<Type> newNode) {

current = root;
if (current == null) {
    current = newNode;
} else if (newNode.getValue().compareTo(current.getValue()) < 0) {

    if (current.getLeft() == null) {
        current.setLeft(newNode);

    } else {
        addNode(current.getLeft(), newNode);
    }
```

Look you are again and again setting the current point equal to root. Which causes StackOverFlow, you should not point to root. You can change it like this: You need to remove this line:

`current = root`

```
if(root == null){
   root = newNode;
   return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're assigning `current = root;` and then on the next line you're checking:

```
if (current == null)
```

This condition will always return false (assuming `root` is not `null`).

What you're doing inside the "else if"s is good but you should remove the first `if` part.

Second, you need to handle the case in which `root` is `null`, better do it in a separate method that first check if root is null and only if it's not - calls this method (addNode) with root and the inserted node

Comment: Thanks! Feel like a dummy, but at least it's working now!